# oracle - sql query select max from each base

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to solve this query where i need to find the the top balance at each base. Balance is in one table and bases are in another table.

This is the existing query i have that returns all the results but i need to find a way to limit it to 1 top result per baseID.

```
SELECT o.names.name t.accounts.bidd.baseID, MAX(t.accounts.balance)
FROM order o, table(c.accounts) t
WHERE t.accounts.acctype = 'verified'
GROUP BY o.names.name, t.accounts.bidd.baseID;
```

- accounts is a nested table.

this is the output

```
      Name        accounts.BIDD.baseID        MAX(T.accounts.BALANCE)
 ---------------  ------------------------- ---------------------------
 Jerard            010                       1251.21 
 john              012                       3122.2 
 susan             012                       3022.2 
 fin               012                       3022.2 
 dan               010                       1751.21
```

What i want the result to display is calculate the highest balance for each baseID and only display one record for that baseID.

So the output would look only display john for baseID 012 because he has the highest.

Any pointers in the right direction would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is cause of the "Name" column. since you have three names mapped to one base id(12), it is considering all three records as unique ones and grouping them individually and not together.
Try to ignore the "Name" column in select query and in the "Group-by" clause.

```
SELECT t.accounts.bidd.baseID, MAX(t.accounts.balance)
FROM order o, table(c.accounts) t
WHERE t.accounts.acctype = 'verified'
GROUP BY t.accounts.bidd.baseID;
```

Comment: Hi, that the issue, just discovered the query works perfectly if i don't select name. However i need to display the name associated in the query and i can't figure a solution. Thanks though. :)

Comment: hi, I have got it working :) :) you can pass it as a sub query and it works like a charm. Example given below: select name,d.* from (select base_id,max(bal) c from table_1 group by base_id)d,table_1 where d.base_id=table_1.base_id and table_1.bal=d.c order by d.base_id asc –

Comment: Hi, sub queries seems like it may work, i tried implementing it but i don't seem to get it to work with a nested table. Thanks, r :)

Comment: I have managed to make it work using your example with slight modification thanks. It seems sub query was the way to go. Thank you.